# H2O Automl in R and Python

Tags: h2o, automl

I have a very simple question. I recently started working on python.

Here is the R codes for H2O Automl

```
aml <- h2o.automl(x = x, y = y, project_name =gtp,max_runtime_secs = 99, max_runtime_secs_per_model = 3600,
                  leaderboard_frame = test,
                  training_frame = train, validation_frame = test,nfolds =0,
                  max_models = 1000,exclude_algos = c("GLM", "DeepLearning", "GBM","DRF","StackedEnsemble"),
                  seed =  22)
```

How can I write these in Python?

```
aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs = 600, exclude_algos = "GLM", "DeepLearning", "GBM","DRF","StackedEnsemble" ,
                seed = 42,project_name =gtp)

aml.train(x = X, 
          y = y, validation_frame =hf_v
          training_frame = hf_train,
          leaderboard_frame = hf_test,)
```

Comment: You can also try MLJAR AutoML https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised Python code: ```automl = AutoML()
automl.fit(X_train, y_train)```

Answer (score 0):

```
aml = H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs = 600, exclude_algos = ["GLM", "DeepLearning", "GBM","DRF","StackedEnsemble"] ,
                seed = 42,project_name = 'gtp')
aml.train(x = X, 
          y = y, validation_frame =hf_v
          training_frame = hf_train,
          leaderboard_frame = hf_test,)
```

Comment: Can you please explain how yours is different and therefore correct. Just dumping some code out gives zero context

Comment: I think only exclude_ algos = [ '.....'] and  project_name = 'gtp' need to be added to the python version of codes. Is there any problem?